# recursive permutation generator for characters

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, permutation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [generate strings with all permutation of character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690367/generate-strings-with-all-permutation-of-character)

I am beginner in c++, and I really need your help. I am doing program for permutation using recursion. Here is my code but output is strange, there are same numbers repeating many times and spaces. I could not find out what the problem is or maybe i need to add smth more. Please help me. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define swap(x,y,t)  ((t)=(x), (x)=(y), (y)=(t))
void perm(char *list, int i, int n);

int main(){
    char a[4]={'a','b','c'};
    perm(a,0,3);
    //cout<<a<<endl;    
    return 0;
}

void perm(char *list, int i, int n){
    int j, temp;
    if (i==n){
        for (j=0; j<=n; j++)
            printf("%c", list[j]);
        printf("     ");
    }
    else {
        for (j=i; j<=n; j++){
            swap(list[i],list[j],temp);
            perm(list,i+1,n);
            swap(list[i],list[j],temp);
            cout<<list<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can save yourself a lot of hassle by simply using the `next_permutation` function built into `<algorithm>`.

Answer (score 1):

The function is correct but you are not calling it correctly.

```
perm(a,0,3);
```

should be

```
perm(a,0,2);
```

Why?

Your for loop:

```
for (j=i; j<=n; j++){
```

goes till `n`, so `n` should be a valid index.

[Works fine](http://ideone.com/cwwWg)

Comment: thanks a lot for your response ^^ )))